# the use for echo without argument in shell scripting

Tags: bash, echo, shell-builtin

I have a following bash script I encountered on the [web](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/set-operations-in-unix-shell-simplified/) that prints the power set of a given lines of elements.

```
p() { [ $# -eq 0 ] && echo || (shift; p "$@") |
        while read r ; do echo -e "$1 $r\n$r"; done }
```

after the first `&&` there is `echo` that does not have any argument.

Here is the code to test it:

```
p $(echo -e "1\n2\n3")
```

Comment: Have you tried it on the CLI? A zero-argument echo just produces a blank line. I'm guessing this is for formatting purposes.

Comment: It is not for formatting purposes. Nothing gets printed out without it.

Comment: `echo` is short for `echo -n $'\x0a'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is for formatting purposes.

```
$ p() { [ $# -eq 0 ] && echo || (shift; p "$@") |
>         while read r ; do echo -e "$1 $r\n$r"; done }
$ p $(echo -e "1\n2\n3")
1 2 3
2 3
1 3
3
1 2
2
1

$ p                 

$
```

Note the blank line between the single `p` and the next prompt. This is `echo`.

Here it is with more readability:

```
p() {
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        echo
    else
        (shift; p "$@") | while read r;
            do echo -e "$1 $r\n$r";
        done
    fi
}
```

The reason you state it didn't work without it is because it does matter that *some* command is there, as otherwise the logic is broken (although, as it is, the logic is kind of strange).

Comment: thanks for the more readable code. It makes sense to have the base case to stop the recursion.

Comment: This is an abuse of recursion.